# Unable to create unique key constraint not found

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "campaign_content", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "campaignContentId", "campaignId", "fieldTag" }))    
public class CampaignContent implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "campaign_content_id")
    private Integer campaignContentId;

    @Column(name = "field_content")
    private String fieldContent;

    @Column(name = "campaign_id")
    private Integer campaignId;

    @Column(name = "field_tag")
    private String fieldTag;
```

With getter and setter.

However I get:

```
caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create unique key constraint (campaignContentId, campaignId, fieldTag) on table campaign_content: campaignContentId, campaignId, fieldTag not found
```

What is wrong?

Comment: try `"campaign_content_id", "campaign_id", "field_tag"`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The name of the column is `campaign_content_id`, not `campaignContentId`. Same thing for the other columns, of course. The `columnNames` attribute expects an array of ... column names. Not an array of Java field or property names.

Comment: I thought that I need the logical names!

Comment: for my `@ManyToOne private Location location;`, the default column name was `location_id` - Location's PK column is named `id`. Without taking the time to confirm it, the pattern seems to be <local-reference-field>_<foreign-pk-field>

Answer (score 7):

In my case this code works, one physical table field name and one entity object member field name.

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"account_id" , "measureDate"})})
```

but this code doesn't work at all with same exception.

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"account_id" , "measure_date"})})
```

Someone reported this bug to hibernate. Check this.
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=986581&view=next

I use

- spring boot
- spring data
- mysql

Comment: i faced the same issue. What i noticed is; if you extend your entity from another entity; for inherited column names, hibernate accepts logical naming(like; createdAt), but for not inherited column names it accepts column name how it appears in database(like; question_id).

Answer (score 1):

If any of constrained column anotated with `@Column(name="...")`:
You need add `@Column(name = "...")` to another constraining columns too.

Answer (score 0):

my problem solved by this 
Your table definition must look like this
@Table(name = "campaign_content", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "campaign_content_id", "campaign_id", "field_tag" }))

Answer (score 0):

For anyone getting this error while using Kotlin, my issue was caused by using `@Column` instead of `@get:Column` on a `var`.  Doh!

Answer (score 0):

Simply if you see detail of error stack trace, it refers error to this class of Hibernate: `InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl` and it will go into this method `processUniqueConstraintHolders`. For better understanding of what every version of your spring boot can behave, This is a good point for debugging.

Totally this error occur when Hibernate needs to know about real name of database column.

This is what I have seen in hibernate 5.6.14:

if you put column name for your field, you have to use it in `UniqueConstraint#columnNames`, otherwise you have to put real field name.(ex: `campaignContentId`)